# Android plugin for Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

Hi I'm trying to use login plugin for Unity. I put java files in Unity and customized AndroidManifest and build.gradle.

Build is success, but when I click the button for login nothing happen.

I think It's about Context problem. But I'm a beginner so I don't know what should I do. :(
Please Help me!!!!!!!!

### This is Unity code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
AndroidJavaClass unityClass;
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity;
AndroidJavaObject unityContext;
AndroidJavaClass plugin;

private void Awake() 
{

//Get Unity Context
unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
unityContext = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.company.example.javaPlugin");
}

public void NavLogin()
{
plugin.Call("CallAndroid", unityContext);
}
}
```

---

### And this is java code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class javaPlugin extends UnityPlayerActivity {

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 Log.d("#####", "onCreate()");
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void CallAndroid(Context context)
{
this.context = context; 
Log.d("#####", "CallAndroid()");

Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, naverLogin.class);
context.startActivity(loginIntent);
      
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Log.d("#####", "onBackPressed()");
//super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

### Edit Java

```
package com.company.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class javaPlugin extends UnityPlayerActivity {

private Context context;
Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
Log.d("#####", "onCreate()");
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

 public void CallAndroid(Activity activity)
{
 this.activity = activity; 
 Log.d("#####", "CallAndroid()");

 Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, naverLogin.class);
 activity.startActivity(loginIntent);
          
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("#####", "onBackPressed()");
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

### Edit Unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
AndroidJavaClass unityClass;
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity;
//AndroidJavaObject unityContext;
AndroidJavaClass plugin;

public void Start() 
{
    //Get Unity Context
    unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    //unityContext = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");
    plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.company.example.javaPlugin");
}

public void NavLogin()
{
    plugin.Call("CallAndroid", unityActivity);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [Demo Project](https://github.com/Spirit30/Unity-Android-Plugin) to help you.

It has C# class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        var unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        var javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.company.example.Test");
        javaClass.CallStatic("CallAndroid", unityActivity);
    }
}
```

Java class:

```
package com.company.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;

public class Test {

    static Activity _activity;

    public static void CallAndroid(Activity activity)
    {
        _activity = activity;
        Log.d("#####", "CallAndroid() - Telemetry is fine.");

        //Continue doing what you need...
    }
}
```

Please make sure you created java class like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdlR.png)

And scripting backend is IL2CPP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this but still nothing happen,,,I export apk and open in AndroidStudio. I can see the onCreate() unde r#### but can't see CallAndroid() And When I click the button, there isn't Debug in Logcat.  I add my edit code in here, Can you check it??

Comment: I've created example project for you.
Please see edited answer.
Good luck with a project!

Comment: I test that code and now have a new problem. I can't use this.activiy = activiy ; with error  "com.company.example.javaPlugin.this' cannot be referenced from a static context"   I'll try to solving this out   .Anyway, Thanks for your effort!!!  :)

Comment: Yeah, I fixed Java code.
Please accept answer.